# MATLAB: Reset Vector at Index

Tags: matlab, vector

Consider the following vectors:

```
>> signals

signals =

 1
 1
 1
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0
 1
 1
 1
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0

>>exits

exits =

 2
10
```

What I need to do is set the 1s to 0s in the `signal` matrix from each value in exits until the value in signals changes. For example, where `exits=2`, I would set the 1s to 0s in the `signal` vector at indicies 2, 3, and 4.

What I have done so far is to identify where the values change in the `signal` vector so that I can identify the start and stop index. For example:

```
>> find(diff(signals)~=0)

ans =

 4
 8
12
```

By doing this, I know I have to set the 1s to 0s from `exits=2` to `signals=4` and `exits=10` to `signals=12`. I am stuck however in figuring out how to do this with no loops.

I realize this may be a bit vague, so here is a simpler example:

```
>> signals

signals =

 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 0
 0
 0
 1
 1
 1

>> exit

exit =

 3

>> rst=exit:find(diff(signals)~=0)

rst =

 3     4     5

signals =

 1
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 1
 1
 1
```

I am basically trying to generalize this simple example to cases where there are multiple `exit` values and multiple different sequences of `signals`.

Comment: What's the reason you don't want to use loops?

Comment: I have 275 lines of code with no loops. I have to be very efficient, hence using MATLAB for vector slicing in the first place.

Comment: @strimp099: when you're optimizing, it's a good idea to use the profiler to find out where your code is wasting time. With more recent versions of Matlab, simple loops can be surprisingly efficient.

Comment: Agree there for sure. Personally I'm fairly indifferent, but the requirements say no loops.

Answer (score 2):

Looping is most certainly going to be the simpler and more readable solution. The way to make this without loops is to reconstruct the `signals`-array, keeping starts and throwing away redundant `exits`.

```
signals = [
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 0
 0
 0
 1
 1
 1];

exit = 3;

startEnd = diff([0;signals]);

%# add the new exit
startEnd(exit) = -1;

%# remove redundant "exits"

startEndIdx = find(startEnd);

deltaEvent = diff([0;startEnd(startEndIdx)]);

deltaIsZero = deltaEvent == 0; %# these are the bad exits

startEnd(startEndIdx(deltaIsZero)) = 0;

%# now we can reconstruct the signals vector
signals = cumsum(startEnd)

signals =

     1
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     1
     1
     1
```